# Extract frames from a video (errors from using grabVideoStills and ffmpeg)

Tags: r, ffmpeg

I'm attempting to extract frame-by-frame images from a set of videos. I've tried to do this using grabVideoStills and ffmpeg but I can't get either to work.

Here is my grabVideoStills command:

```
  grabVideoStills(
    01_H35_combined_small.mp4,
  imageDir = "C:/Users/pb/OneDrive/PD/MAG/split_stimuli",
  overWriteDir = FALSE,
  sampleWindow = 1
)
```

And I get the following error:

```
    imageDir = "C:/Users/pb/OneDrive/PD/MAG/split_stimuli",
Error: unexpected ',' in "imageDir = "C:/Users/pb/OneDrive/PD/MAG/split_stimuli","
>   overWriteDir = FALSE,
Error: unexpected ',' in "  overWriteDir = FALSE,"
>   sampleWindow = 1
> )
Error: unexpected ')' in ")"
```

Here is my ffmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg - i 01_H35_combined_small.mp4 %04d.png
```

And I get the following error message:

```
Error: unexpected numeric constant in "ffmpeg - i 01"
```

One thought I had about this error is that it doesn't like the number at the start of the filename, I've tried using quotation marks but it yields a similar error:

```
Error: unexpected string constant in "ffmpeg - i "01_H35_combined_small.mp4""
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the **av** package you can do:

```r
library(av)
av_video_images("yourFile.mp4", destdir = "destinationFolder", format = "png")
```